# Why are dense set useful in analysis

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Consider the following theorem from Rudin's Real-and complex analysis.

**3.14 Theorem** For $1 \leq p < \infty, C_c(X)$ is dense in $L^p(\mu)$.

What I don't understand is why this result is useful in proofs. I heard few examples of where in order to define functionals in $L^p(\mu)$ you can firstly define them in $C_c(X)$ and then extend them using Hahn Banach theorem.

Is this the main application? definition of maps and functionals?

**Update**: If anyone could point to the proofs of results that actually use density of $C_c(X)$ in $L^p(\mathbb{\mu})$ that would be useful.

Comment: Yes, sort of. For example, if you want to check some inequality for functions in $L^p$, sometimes it suffices to check for a dense subset (simple functions, continuous functions....)

Comment: Think about what might be a useful property for those working in numerical analysis and approximation theory.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I can picture those, I can picture what sort of theoretical constructions you can do with them though.

Comment: @ArcticChar can you give few examples?

Comment: One practical benefit is that you can approximate an $L^p(\mu)$ function arbitrarily well with a $C_c(X)$ function. This means that you can very often prove something about all $C_c(X)$ functions and then extend the proof nicely to all of $L^p(\mu)$.

Comment: Try to prove that the map $\Bbb{R}\to L^1(\Bbb{R}), x \mapsto T_x f$ defined by $T_x f(y)=f(y-x)$ is continuous for each $f \in L^1$. This is quite easy for $C_c^\infty$ functions and can then be lifted "by density".

Comment: @PhoemueX how do you "lift" by density?

Comment: The Riemann-Lebesgue lemma for the Fourier transform can be proved by partial integration for $C^1_c(\mathbb R)$ and then for $L^1(\mathbb R)$ by approximation.

Comment: I would say that **every** estimate in modern partial differential equations is proven on spaces of smooth functions and then extended by density.

Comment: @PhoemueX, why not make this an answer?  It's proof appears many places on this site so a link should suffice.

Comment: I'd like to point out that Hahn-Banach is completely irrelevant here. The extension is unique and given by an explicit formula, so please don't mix the AC with this.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro That's a bold (and quite inspiring) statement. I think I could find a few examples (especially in the nonlinear world) where I don't know of a density-based argument and cannot imagine one. But that's a topic of a very different discussion.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the most important results in real/functional analysis. It is used in proofs of other important real/functional analysis theorems. One I can think of is the famous transformation formula.

Your theorem is especially important in the case $X = \mathbb{R}^n$ (or sufficiently regular subsets of the latter) and $\mu$ being the Lebesgue-measure. The next step is to prove that $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n) \cap W^{1, p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is dense in the sobolev spaces $W^{1, p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ where $1 \leq p < \infty$. Consequences of this are e.g. the chain rule for Sobolev functions, fundamental theorem of calculus for Sobolev functions etc... . The argument is always to prove the desired result for a differentiable function, which is usually a classical calculus I,  II or III result. Then we prove that if we approximate (into the Sobolev space) the classical result will not be distorted. So we use the dense set, because it has some nice properties that we did not enjoy before.

Some more (huge) consequences of your theorem are the Fundamental theorem of Calculus of Variations (and therefore the Euler-Lagrange-Eq.), Poincaré's-inequality (and therefore existence of weak solutions for elliptic PDEs like the Dirichlet-PDE), continuity of the trace operator for sobolev spaces, Gagliardo-Nirenberg type inequalities (and therefore Sobolev-embeddings which have countless applications in PDE theory) and plenty plenty more.

One additional **remark**: Assume that $V$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces, $A \subseteq V$ is dense and $T:A \rightarrow Y$ is a countinuous, linear functional. You can explicitly use density here (note that Hahn-Banach does not apply if $Y \neq \mathbb{R}$) to extend $T$: Let $v \in V$ and $(v_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq A$ a sequence that converges to $v$ (i.e. it is Cauchy). Then
$$
\lVert Tv_k - Tv_m \rVert_Y \leq \lVert T \rVert \lVert v_k - v_m \rVert_V \overset{k, m \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0
$$
So $(Tv_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq Y$ is Cauchy and therefore, because of $Y$ being Banach, has a limit $\tilde{v}$. We can then set $Tv := \tilde{v}$.

Comment: OP asked about importance of density of smooth functions in $L^{p}$.  It's not clear that OP knows what $W^{1,p}$ is.

Comment: Well, OP asked for it. Since he or she does not know, I am here to tell him.

Comment: It's fine, they're Sobolev spaces.